# Padding in select not working in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a select HTML element and I put a css class

```
 .selectbox{
   padding:0.3em;
 }
```

but this is not working in IE 7.Besides IE7 it is working in all other browsers.Does anyone has a fix for this?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or a link we can look at ?

Comment: Then we probably can not help you

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of web developing ;-)

Comment: no jsfiddle or a link it's just that the padding for select works in all browsers except IE 7.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 7 does not allow padding to be set on `select` elements.

These kinds of restrictions are common with form controls because they may use OS control elements.

One workaround would be to turn off the select border, create a surrounding element, and give that element padding.

Comment: Any solution then for this problem like IE HACK or something else?

Comment: Your only hack is to create some sort of custom drop down that acts as a select element using JavaScript. The more you try to mess with standard form elements, the more you'll be disappointed. Take a look at what your select element looks like in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this-

http://quirksmode.org/

IE also requires `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration in older versions.

Comment: Tell me what declaration should I use ?

Comment: In fact, *all* IE versions require a doctype to avoid quirks mode. And even other browsers too.